# BDE with Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

I have an old application running BDE under Delphi 7, and have now bought Delphi XE. Can I expect big problems if I try to stick with BDE under Delphi XE? Or will converting save me time in the end?

Issue 2: I have seen some people trying to use the included Installaware installer to install BDE and a database alias etc, but I am not sure if anyone succeeded. Is it possible?

Rgds PM

Comment: The BDE has been deprecated for about a decade now. I keep being surprised running into people still using it. (Of course, I stopped long before it was deprecated; the BDE was really only good if you were using Paradox tables, and I didn't do so.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you stick to 32 bit applications, it will work. There is no BDE for 64 bit.

But as everybody and his mother will point out: The BDE has been deprecated years ago and sooner or later you will run into trouble. E.g. you might not be able to install it on Windows 7 or your customers might fail to do that.

We are currently in the process of moving away from it and it is a pain in the lower back because it has been used in so many utilities for too long and there isn't quite an alternative for it for accessing dbase tables.

Comment: Thanks for constructive input! Have you actually run into problems with  customers that cant install BDE into Windows 7?

Comment: No, only with customers who don't want to install it or (very rarely) already have an existing install with some very odd defaults.